# Javafx FXML Media Player play same Video in two windows simultaneously

Tags: javafx, media-player, fxml

im have a simple Media Player created in Java with Javafx FXML.

Now what i want to achieve, is to play the video also in a second window, sadly ive got no clue how this is done. I searched other posts about the same question but found nothing what would help me.

Here's the code

simplemediaPlayer.java :

```
package simplemediaplayer;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class simplemediaPlayer extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setTitle("Media Player");
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent doubleClicked) {
            if(doubleClicked.getClickCount() == 2) {
                if(stage.isFullScreen()) {
                    stage.setFullScreen(false);
                } else {
                    stage.setFullScreen(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    Parent roota = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("dualmodeWindow.fxml"));
    Stage stagea = new Stage();
    Scene scenea = new Scene(roota);

    stagea.setTitle("Second Window");

    stagea.setScene(scenea);
    stagea.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

FXMLDocumentController.java :

```
package simplemediaplayer;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@FXML
private MediaView mediaView;

private String filePath;

@FXML
private Slider volSlider;

@FXML
private Slider minSlider;

@FXML
private void openvidFile(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Select a File (*.mp4)", "*.mp4");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    filePath = file.toURI().toString();

    if(filePath != null) {
        Media media = new Media(filePath);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
        DoubleProperty width = mediaView.fitWidthProperty();
        DoubleProperty height = mediaView.fitHeightProperty();

        width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mediaView.sceneProperty(), "width"));
        height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mediaView.sceneProperty(), "height"));

        volSlider.setValue(mediaPlayer.getVolume() * 100);
        volSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(volSlider.getValue()/100);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
                minSlider.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());
            }
        });

        minSlider.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(minSlider.getValue()));
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}

@FXML
private void playVid(ActionEvent event) {
    mediaPlayer.play();
    mediaPlayer.setRate(1);
}

@FXML
private void pauseVid(ActionEvent event) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

@FXML
private void stopVid(ActionEvent event) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}

@FXML
private void exitProg(ActionEvent event) {
    System.exit(0);
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}    

}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>

 <StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="simplemediaplayer.FXMLDocumentController">
  <children>
  <MediaView fx:id="mediaView" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" />
  <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
     <top>
        <MenuBar fx:id="topMenu" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
          <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openvidFile" text="Open" />
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exitProg" text="Close" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          </menus>
        </MenuBar>
     </top>
     <bottom>
        <VBox fx:id="botMenu" alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="84.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
           <children>
              <Slider fx:id="minSlider" />
              <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="600.0">
                 <children>
                    <Button fx:id="openClick" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openvidFile" text="Open">
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets right="10.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                    </Button>
                    <Button fx:id="playClick" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#playVid" text="Play">
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets right="10.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                    </Button>
                    <Button fx:id="pauseClick" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pauseVid" text="Pause">
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets right="20.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                    </Button>
                    <Slider fx:id="volSlider" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="140.0" />
                    <Button fx:id="dualmodeButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Dual Mode">
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets left="30.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                    </Button>
                 </children>
              </HBox>
           </children>
        </VBox>
     </bottom>
  </BorderPane>
 </children>
 </StackPane>
```

and i created a second fxml window which only contains a stackpane and a mediaview.

dualmodeWindow.fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="simplemediaplayer.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
  <MediaView fx:id="secmediaView" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" />
</children>
</StackPane>
```

Ive tried to give the mediaView on the second window the same id as the mediaView on the main Window but no video appear on the second window.

Would be nice if someone can help me with this.

Comment: You need to find a way to share the same MediaPlayer between both the MediaView instances.

Comment: Yes ok, i tried now, to set the second mediaView i have to the same MediaPlayer, but when i do that the MediaPlayer dosnt work anymore. How do i share the same MediaPlayer between both MediaViews?

Comment: If you have tried something and it doesn't work, please update your question. Also, try to first test it without FXML and controllers for simplicity. This will also allow your to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which you could post in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a second media player with the same media object, and then set this second media player to the second media view.  According to the documentation, a media player can have only one media object.